# TextArea Resizing in Dart during DOM Initialization

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to make a text area that resizes dynamically in Dart based on the height of its contents.

I have a textarea element defined in a polymer element in Dart like so:

```dart
<polymer-element name="page-content">
   <template>
      {{title}}
      <ul>
         <template repeat="{{element in elist | enumerate}}">
            <li value={{element.index}}><textarea class="{{element.value.type}}" resize="none" on-keypress="{{resize}}" on-change="{{updateDatabase}}">{{element.value.content}}</textarea><div on-click="{{deleteElement}}">X</div></li>
         </template>
      </ul>
   </template>
</polymer-element>
```

When any text is entered into the `textarea`, the `resize` method is called and properly resizes the text-area to adjust its height appropriately.

I am not sure how to call the `resize` method right when the element is loaded into the DOM. I have tried adding `on-load="{{resize}}"` to the textarea or even querying all the textareas and adjusting their sizes. Nothing seems to be working. My intutition tells me there should be an easy way to do this.

If it helps, my resize method in dart looks like this:

```dart
void resize(Event event, var detail, var target) {
    Element element = event.target;
    print(element.scrollHeight);

    element.style.height = "1px";
    element.style.height = "${element.scrollHeight}px";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that I worked out is very similar to what [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer) suggested. It queries the shadow DOM (something I did not think to do) to get all the text areas at once (instead of just one) and update their heights accordingly.

The method could be in `attached()` or after any place where the content is dynamically fetched from the database in my case.

```dart
void updatePageSizes() {
    var items = shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("textarea");
    var j = items.iterator;
    while (j.moveNext()) {
      j.current.style.height = "${element.scrollHeight}px";
      j.current.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
  }
```

Also, I figured out that, to my knowledge, it is not possible to call a function in Dart from each element added in an enumerated list in a polymer element. I guess this is just a limitation of Dart.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question.
I think the best approach would be to wrap the `textarea` in some `autosize-textarea` and there add

```dart
<polymer-element name="autosize-textarea">
  <template>
    <textarea id="inner" class="{{element.value.type}}" resize="none" 
      on-keypress="{{resize}}">
      {{element.value.content}}</textarea>
   </template>
</polymer-element>
```

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('autosize-textarea')
class AutosizeTextarea extends PolymerElement {

  AutosizeTextarea.created() : super.created();

  @published
  Element element;

  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    resize(null, null, null);
  }

  void resize(Event event, var detail, var target) {
    Element textarea $['inner'];
    print(textarea.scrollHeight);

    textarea.style.height = "1px";
    textarea.style.height = "${textarea.scrollHeight}px";
  }
}
```

and the use it like

```dart
<link rel="import" href="autosize_textarea.html">
<polymer-element name="page-content">
  <template>
    {{title}}
    <ul>
      <template repeat="{{element in elist | enumerate}}">
        <li value={{element.index}}>
          <autosize-textarea on-change="{{updateDatabase}}" element="{{element}}></autosize-textarea>
          <div on-click="{{deleteElement}}">X</div>
        </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

I'm not sure if I understand your code correctly because you named the item created from `template repeat` `element` and also the element you got from `event.target`. I'm not sure if/how they are related.
Not tested but I think it should work.

Comment: The code you provided did not work. But it got me thinking in the direction of: "What if there was a method call inside dart that performed this resize function all at once?" similar to how the code you provided handles this case.

The `resize(Event event, var detail, var target)` method is a standard event call for a certain element `target` and I don't think it would be good practice to handle a call to resize all the text areas in that method.